# Cypher - Change text properties to collections

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am pretty new to Cypher.  I have a bunch of nodes with the Person label.

```
Match (n:Person) return n;
```

returns results like:

```
Node[21]{title:"Senior Developer",phone:"504-342-2222",email:"stevenson@someco.com",name:"Steve Stevenson"}
```

I want to change the phone and email properties to be collections, so that you can have
multiple phone numbers or emails per person.  Is there a Cypher query so that I can change those properties to be collections, and put the current values in the collections for all Person nodes?  TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
MATCH (n:Person)
SET n.phone = [n.phone]
SET n.email = [n.email];
```